# Pseudo Distributed Mode Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have installed  **Pseudo Distributed mode** **Hadoop 2.7.3** in Mac & did all **Configuration** which is specified in **Plural Sight**. I Copied **Csv file** from Local to hdfs. But next day when i searched for files , it is not present in hdfs and removed automatically. Is there any other conf setting so that my files are not loss?

core-site.xml

```xml
<configuration> 
   <property> 
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name> 
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
   </property> 
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```xml
<configuration> 
   <property> 
      <name>dfs.replication</name> 
      <value>1</value> 
   </property> 
</configuration>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Post your `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`

Comment: I did below setting for core-site.xml & hdfs-site.xml

-->core-site.xml
    <configuration>
  <property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
    </configuration> 
   
-->hdfs-site.xml
 -> <configuration>
  <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
  </property>
    </configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these properties to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property> 
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
   <value>/home/username/hadoop-dfs/name</value> 
</property>
<property> 
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
   <value>/home/username/hadoop-dfs/data</value> 
</property>
```

The metadata and data blocks are stored under `/tmp` by default as it is the value of `hadoop.tmp.dir`. The contents inside `/tmp` are deleted on reboot.

After adding these properties, format the `namenode` and start the services.

Comment: Thank you for reply,
Should we have to create  "hadoop-dfs" directory under username & "name" , "data" directory under "hadoop-dfs"?

Comment: Create `hadoop-dfs` only. `name` and `data` directories will be created by the namenode and datanode respectively. And for Mac, change the home path accordingly.