# Namenode not start after restart pc (hadoop 2.7.3)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hadoop, namenode, bigdata

i've configured hadoop 2.7.3 on ubuntu 16.04 and run all (word count and other mapReduce run all).
after restart pc, i launch start-dfs, but the namenode not started. other guide says remove temporay directory, but i don't have it.

that are my files:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share the name node logs  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pseudo Distributed Mode Hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177670/pseudo-distributed-mode-hadoop)

Comment: @DeepanRam this is the log: 2017-04-04 15:25:36,095 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-alessio/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

Comment: The folder and structure under the "/tmp" are deleted after reboot. 
Try changing them to local structure and try to give 775 permissions to them and restart the services.

Comment: @DeepanRam how i can change "/tmp" and give 775 permissions?

Comment: chmod 775 -R <dir_name>.
Please change the **dfs.namenode.name.dir** and **dfs.datanode.data.dir** in the hdfs-site.xml with local dir (other than tmp) and give the permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Create the folders like below:
      -- sudo mkdir /dfs
      -- sudo chown username:username /dfs/*
      -- sudo chmod 755 /dfs/
      -- cd /dfs
      If the machine is name node then:
          -- mkdir nn 
      if data node: 
          -- mkdir data

Step 2:
add below properties in hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
                <value>/dfs/nn</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
                <value>/dfs/data</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>


</configuration>
step 3:
 format the namenode: hadoop namenode -format
step 4:
 start all services
```

Comment: now don't start datanode (and namenode)! there are errors on paths of namenode and datanode (dfs/nn and dfs/data)

Comment: ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode. org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateExce‌​ption: Directory /tmp/hadoop-alessio/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

Comment: yes, but at every restart, the folder tmp are deleted, and the the namenode is not created

Comment: could you share the log message for "hadoop namenode -format"?

Comment: send me the log message to this mail id: kanagaraj.vp@gmail.com

Comment: i have clearly mentioned the steps but i am not sure whether he followed all the steps or not. could you tell me in which part i am making confusions

Comment: You have mentioned the paths as `/dfs/nn` and `/dfs/data`. The path `/dfs` does not exist by default. If the OP is new to linux, he wouldn't know and the format would still fail. Instruct the OP that such directories must be created and should be owned by the superuser.